# VS2015 cannot fathom static inline functions

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, intellisense

I have the following function defined in a header file of a visual studio makefile project that eventually builds in `c` using `msys-rtems`:

```
static inline UInt32 timer_now() {
    ...
```

Where the type `UInt32` is a `typedef` from a included header file:

```
typedef unsigned long UInt32;
```

I get the following problems with my intellisense because of that function:

1. Intellisense suggests `inline` is not a type name. `>Error: Variable 'inline' is not a type name`
2. Intellisense thinks that the definition of `UInt32` is this function instead of the `typedef unsigned long`.
3. If i remove the `inline` keyword everything works fine (except that i dont want to because this is a function we want inlined).
4. I don't think it is fully to do with my `typedef UInt32` because if i swap this out with `unsigned long` i still get the same problem.
5. There are a bunch of other functions below this one using `static inline double` which dont have any error unless they are moved to be the first function. Then they experience the same error.

I have tried restarting VS2015 and deleting the `SQL` database file. I have played with various intellisense options to no avail. **Is this an intellisense bug?**

As an additional note, a quick look over the remainder of the project makes it look like the first `inline` function in any h file has this problem.

Visual studio bug opened [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1849755/intellisense-incorrect-identification-of-problem-with-inline#).

As a more minimal example I reduced the header file to just:

```
#ifndef SERVOSCHED_H 
#define SERVOSCHED_H

typedef unsigned long UInt32;
static inline UInt32 timer_now() {}

#endif
```

And i still get this:

[image]

### Why I don't want to just turn off intellisense.

This isn't just affecting my intellisense, otherwise i wouldnt care. The real problem is that it thinks `UInt32` is **declared** in this line:

```
static inline UInt32 timer_now() {
```

ie. When i go to definition on any `UInt32` use it takes me to this line. But its worse, because of this *ANYTHING* that is declared as type `UInt32` cannot be found as defined. As in if i have this anywhere in our massive code base:

```
UInt32 ii;
...
for (ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii) {
```

Then -

1. VS thinks `ii` is undefined.
2. You cannot follow `ii` to its definition - which is crazy annoying.

We use `UInt32` and `Int32` literally everywhere and anything declared with these types cannot be easily found which is a huge problem.

### Why i dont want to just change the `inline`

I know that the `static inline` keywords might not do anything on this particular code. Its not that i don't want to change it. It is that i cant change it. This code is compiled as c in GCC 3.4.5. The compiler is a cross compiler written for RTEMS under the Power PC 5200 board BSP. How do you think it will change the assembly code when you just remove the inline? Don't know? Neither do I. Given that this is running a real time system that can affect safety functionality. I don't just not want to change it. I cant change it until such time as we decide to upgrade the compiler as well.

### Current Workaround

In order to fix this for now i have defined the following `typedef`:

```
typedef UInt32 inlineUInt32;
```

and have used this instead of `UInt32` in the `static inline` function definitions. This fixes the described problem with `UInt32`, but i have made a change in running code (That is built with a makefile) to please Visual Studio which is **stupid**.

Comment: It looks like it.  It compiles right?

Comment: @NathanOliver This is a makefile project and it compiles just fine. That is with GCC though.

Comment: `inline` is only a hint; even if you don't mark it `inline`, the compiler will still treat it as a candidate for being inlined.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee, correct, but is there any reason i should not mark inline? Surely not just to satisfy intellisense ....

Comment: It compiles on VS2008.  Do you have a missing semicolon on the line before the word static?

Comment: @cup It compiles fine in VS2015. Its only intellisense that has a problem.

Comment: Not a problem with intellisense on VS2008.

Comment: @cup yep, so i suspect maybe a VS2015 intellisense bug ...

Comment: I recommend not listening to Intellisense.  It often disagrees with the errors from the compiler (or absence of errors).  For more accurate help, get a *static analysis* tool.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am fine not listening to its build advice. But this is causing 2 problems. 1. Go to definition doesn't work for the some of the types that we have defined. 2. Squiggly lines everywhere (I know we can turn them off but im trying to see if i can get it working first).

Comment: Are you definitely compiling C++ rather than C? (`inline` behaves differently in each language)

Comment: @M.M It is a makefile project. Although the code is compiled (in `c`) using GCC, this is done by a batch file called by visual studio. As for the language that intellisense uses to parse it, i have no idea how to determine if it thinks it is C or C++.

Comment: If it is C perhaps you should use the C tag rather than the C++ tag for this question.  To confirm what intellisense is doing you could add some code that is clearly illegal in C++, e.g. `int new;`

Comment: @M.M I suspect it is at least C++11 because `new` ,`class` and `auto` are all recognized as keywords (and don't cause any intellisense problems).

Comment: @Ben if the code contains those keywords (not being used as identifiers) then it will not be able to be compiled in C (using gcc or any other compiler)

Comment: @M.M So i added those keywords to check intellisense which is clearly checking for c++ code. The code is being compiled as `c` using an external compiler (`mingw`). What i am concerned with is intellisense telling me that an inline keyword is a type name.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, do you mean that the code contains new, class and auto; or you just added them now to test intellisense? If the latter then maybe look for a way to let intellisense know that this is C rather than C++ (i'm not sure whether this is possible)

Comment: Also it would be good to have an MCVE (e.g. check that the problem still happens when your file is just a single line `static inline void f() {}`

Comment: @M.M Yes, as per your advice i added them to check intellisense. The code is absolutely running C. I dont think there is a way to convert intellisense to using C, at least i cant find it. As for the MCVE, i can not reproduce it using a small function created from scratch. I am working on stripping away stuff as i go, but its difficult with the size of the code base.

Comment: @M.M Also yes, when the funtion definition is the only thing in the file it will still have the bug. (also i had the typedef include).

Comment: I disable intellisense error reporting because it is often wrong.

Comment: @NeilKirk As i have explained, its not just affecting my intellisense. Bassiclly it thinks the type `UInt32` is **declared** in this `inline` function. Which means that anything declared as UInt32 (which is a lot of things) cannot be followed to definition. I might add this to the question ...

Comment: Have you tried `inline static`?

Comment: You ask "Is this an intellisense bug?". No, it isn't a general VS2015 intellisense bug. My VS2015 (Community Edition) intellisense handles your code example perfectly well. Perhaps something in your environment is causing it?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a *new project* ?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `Inline static` does avoid the major problem described and fixed with my workaround. But inline is still not recognized as a keyword. So good catch.

Comment: @cdmh I wasn't able to either, thats what makes this so strange. Looking through my project properties i cant see anything out of the ordinary. It is a makefile project so the only thing affecting this should be the Intellisense options under `NMake`. The only thing i have in there are a bunch of include directories (all which exist) and some pre-processor definitions. Can you think of anything else that could cause this?

Comment: @Ben if you don't already, try setting "Always Use Fallback Location" to True, and set a Fallback Location (e.g. `C:\Temp`) in Options|Text Editor|Advanced. There's also a bunch of options for Intellisense in there, but I've never changed any of those from their default.

Comment: @cdmh It was already set ... :(

Comment: What file extension is the makefile generating?

Comment: @Casey I don't see how that is relevant, but it creates ab bunch of folders with object files. It will eventually compile and link together using the `rtems-msys` cross compiler and create an image file with the RTEMS operating system and our run-time code.

Comment: @Casey - For your edit, i believe this is one of the few times when the `c++` and `c` tags are necessary, since i am building in `c` and VS is interpreting everything as `c++`

Comment: The reason I was asking is the default behavior for Visual Studio is "interpret the language based on the file extension" and I was thinking that was the root of the problem. Visual Studio sees a `.cpp` and regardless of the content compiles it as a C++ file, but obviously this is not the case. :P

Comment: C89 (that's the C standard supported by Microsoft) has no `inline` keyword. Why do you expect intellisense to recognize it?

Comment: Why does intellisense recognize `auto` and `class` in `c` files? but not inline? Also i didnt know that MS only supported C89, seems kinda bad ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual C++ IntelliSense service when processing C source files (or headers included by C source files).  This bug was reported several months ago on Microsoft Connect:  [IntelliSense does not accept "inline" C99 functions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1368125/intellisense-does-not-accept-inline-c99-functions).  The bug has been fixed and the fix will appear in the next update to Visual Studio 2015.

A workaround (while you await the next update to Visual Studio 2015) would be to define a macro named `inline` that expands to nothing, and to guard that macro so that it is only defined when the Visual C++ IntelliSense service is parsing the file.

```
#if defined _MSC_VER && defined __EDG__ && !defined __cplusplus
    #define inline
#endif
```

Ideally this macro definition would be placed in one common header that is included by everything in your project.  If no such header exists, then you can place it into its own header then force-include it at the top of every file using [the `/FI` compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx).  (This is generally inadvisable, but since you'd only be using this as a temporary workaround for this IntelliSense issue, it's probably okay.)

Comment: Perfect! Answer to the question and a great work-around. +1

Answer (score -4):

From the example given, it is clear that 'inline' is not needed there, and can be safely removed. Expalanation:

1. if timer_now() is defined inside the class, inline is not needed there, since definitions inside the class are always inline. Remove to reduce the clutter.
2. timer_now() CAN NOT be a definition of free-standing function in the header file, since in this case it would not be marked 'static'
3. If timer_now() is a definiton withing .cpp file, inline is not needed, since if the function can be inlined by the compiler, it will be inlined, and there is no requirement to mark it inline.

Comment: 1. Its not. 2. It CAN be a standalone static inline: http://ideone.com/R0KeZZ 3. Its not. My objective here is not to change the code in any way. It is to figure out why intellisense thinks that `inline` is a type name.

Comment: @Ben, while it can, it should not. Nothing is more deceiving than freestanding static functions in headers, and whenever I see one, "I reach for my gun". Btw, your example is not an illustration of the topic, since you are doing case 3. In this case, inline is deceiving and rubbish.
Of course, you might not want to clean up your code from rubbish, but it is your code and you are having problems with it, not me.

Comment: I would be happy for suggestions about how to fix the issue with intellisense. As for the code, it is not mine i am simply responsible for porting it from VS2008 to VS2015. I am not looking to change any of the running code because it builds on an old compiler and minor modifications can cause big problems on the cross compiled device. Regardless of whether it is good code or not, would you expect intellisense to throw the error described on a c++ keyword? I think not.

Comment: Also, I'm doing case 2. I know the ideone example is in a cpp file but the equivalent with a header file works also.

Comment: 2. Incorrect (although probably true). 3. Incorrect (although sometimes true).

Comment: @NeilKirk, care to elaborate? What is 'incorrect' about my statements?

Comment: You can put static free-standing functions in a header file, although it's usually not a good idea. Functions that can be inlined are not necessarily inlined by the compiler. Although it's up to the compiler, some real ones do take into account the inline keyword when determining the probability of inlining a function, so it can make sense to make such a function inline.